Cannot install any package with pip install - could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xxx
I am trying to download python-docx via pip install python-docx, but it gives the error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-docx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-docx

Then I tried to download another package Aspose-cells like
pip install aspose-cells
pip install aspose-words

But I get the same error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aspose-words (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aspose-words

And then I found that this error would appear for any package that I tried to install.
Most of the answers that I found online points to the version being too outdated or OS issues, but I checked the versions - they are both the latest (python 3.12 and pip v24.0). I am on windows. PyPI server has not blacklisted my IP address neither.
What should I do?
Thank you!

Can you check with python 3.11?

Do you know how to use a different version of python? I downloaded 3.11 from the website but on cmd mine still shows 3.12

Did you try python -m pip install python-docx

You need to lower your Python version to between 3.7 and 3.11, as shown in this list.
target-version = ["py37", "py38", "py39", "py310", "py311"]

REF
Bonus: You can check your Python version using python3 --version on Linux and python --version on Windows.

Hi, thank you for the answer. I am now on python 3.11.9. But I still get the exact same error.

I find another possible cause. I am using a corporate network.

If you are encountering the same error, it may be due to an incorrect connection request with PyPI packages. Try changing machines or using a different network. If the issue stems from network configuration, you will need to manually find a solution by examining the pip.py file.
